# modified logistic distribution domain field

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a distribution with pdf

$$f(x) = \frac{e^z}{k {(1+e^z)}^n }, \text{ where } z= \frac{x- \alpha} k$$

and $k\sim \operatorname{exponential}(\lambda)$. If n=2 it is the logistic distribution. Does anyone know whick distribution is this? What's change in th domain field of $f(x)$? when not equals 2 or how to find it? i want use this property :the interval of f(x)= 1.

Comment: Please don't [delete a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343397/whats-the-domain-field-of-the-pdf-or-how-to-find-it) and post it again as a new one. You are expected to improve your previous posts and wait much longer for responses.

Comment: @Max sorry for that, i did it cause now i know it looks like a certain distribution and i already modified it multiple times.